# Meringue Imitation to practice decoration

Tags: cake, meringue, decorating

Does exist a product in market of imitation of not eatable meringue with the same consistency?

This in order to practice decoration and re-use several times the " practice meringue" without the need to make and waste real meringue.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: This is going to sound idiotic, but I use spray-foam sealant and wear latex or vinyl gloves. I usually have some of the sealant in the shop, and the amount I need for experimenting (or, as in your case, practice) isn't much, so it's cheap at twice the price.

Comment: Hello Shalryn, thanks for answer. It sounds awesome for me. I don't have experience with spray-foam sealant. Is it toxic or sticky? Do you use the same nozzles and piping bags for your experiments?

Comment: It is sticky, but you can get types that aren't toxic. For experimenting, I buy cheap nozzles from the dollar store and team them with old bread bags, produce bags, or zip- or slide-lock-type bags. When I'm done. I  just dispose of the lot and don't have to take any chances safety-wise. I don't use my good supplies until I'm using the real meringue.

Comment: Excellent Shalryn, thanks so much for share your idea, I'm new to this about making cakes, meringue etc, but I don't like to use actual food ingredients only to practice. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

they make this stuff called Presto Pastry Pride ready to whip topping. It's pretty similar in consistency and can be piped very well. It's also pretty great as frosting. I think it would be perfect for you and it's pretty cheap. You can find it in the frozen section at smart and final.

Comment: Hello bigsandwich, thanks for share that info, I'll try to look for that product in my country or in internet.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using canned beans, or cooking dried beans, regularly you will have the canning/cooking liquid at no additional cost - this can be collected in the fridge and turned into so called aquafaba meringue for the cost of sugar and acid. It is actually edible if you keep the bean liquid in a food-safe way. I will refer to howto articles across the web, since aquafaba techniques are still evolving.